# How to you put a prepared statement index value into a global variable

Tags: java

I need to use the data entered into the preparedstatement.setString(1,input.nextLine()) into a public variable and use it in a different class. Please help.

```java
String sql = "insert into customer(customerName, customerAddress, column_name) 
              values(?,?,?)"; //  Initialize a string with the SQL query
 
System.out.println();
System.out.println("___________________________Hello Customer
                    ___________________________");

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql); 
System.out.print("Enter Your Name : ");
preparedStatement.setString(1,input.nextLine());
 
System.out.print("Enter Your  Address : ");
preparedStatement.setString(2, input.nextLine());
```

I don't know too much about Java, so please dumb it down for me.

Comment: What and where is the index variable?

Comment: Java doesn't have "global variables" as such. It is unclear what you want to do.

Comment: You should create a database object, which has an `addCustomer(customer)` method, where the customer object should have `customerName`, `customerAddress` and `column_name` attributes.
In the database object, you can declare a prepared statement object for all database operations.